# Set Dockpanel width and height as same as Window width and height in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have created main window in this window created dockpanel for binding user control value in main window like as below,

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.DMMainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       ResizeMode="NoResize"
       WindowState="Maximized" 
       WindowStyle="None"
       WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
       Height="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}"
       Width="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}">
    <DockPanel Width="1254" Height="1200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" x:Name="mainPanel" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</Window>
```

In this code you can see given width and height for dockpanel. I need this height and width need to bind as same as window width. I have used actual width and height and also sizetocontent but nothing happened as expected. Please give your suggestion.

Comment: When used as the top-level container, `DockPanel` will automatically fill the `Window` parent. You should not be setting `Width` and `Height` explicitly at all. In the code above, you seem to be forcing the `DockPanel` to a size different from that used for the `Window` size, so of course it won't wind up the right size. Please explain more precisely what you what the code to do, why you think what you have should do that, and what the code does instead. It is not at all clear what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add Stretch property as below,

```
<DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Margin="0,0,0,0" x:Name="mainPanel" />
```

Hope it will work

Comment: Looks like "Arun D" helps "arun d"? Your alter ego will always help you.

Comment: I cant catch you macieqqq

Answer (score 5):

As you are using dock panel you do not need to set it explicitly. Incase you want , you can restrict further by using minimum height and width, but no mandatory.

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.DMMainWindow"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             ResizeMode="NoResize"
             WindowState="Maximized" 
             WindowStyle="None"
             WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
             Height="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}"
             Width="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}">
             <DockPanel x:Name="mainPanel" 
                        MinHeight ="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}" 
                        MinWidth ="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}"  />

 </Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.DMMainWindow"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         ResizeMode="NoResize"
         WindowState="Maximized" 
         WindowStyle="None"
         WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
         Height="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}"
         Width="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}">
         <DockPanel x:Name="mainPanel" />
 </Window>
```

Comment: Try this it will exactly fit to your window.